# How to fix low quality raster image on HERE javascript map v3.1

Tags: javascript, gis, here-api, here-maps-rest

After upgrading to V3.1 of the HERE Maps Java Script SDK, the raster image quality has been noticeably reduced. Comparing our production site vs the updated one with the same view port shows v3.1 has poor image quality on all raster layers.

Have tried disabling fractional zoom and specifying pixelRatio based on the window. The image tiles being downloaded look the same based on network traffic.

```
    var hereMap = new H.Map(
        document.getElementById(mapCanvasDiv),
        defaultLayers.raster.terrain.map,
        {
            zoom: mapOptions.zoom,
            center: mapOptions.center,
            pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
        });
```

I'd expect the same quality of image rendering for raster layers as the previous version.

Comment: HERE, 3 months later and this is still a major problem, the WebGL renderer is very bad at rendering raster layers.

Answer (score 0):

Please use raster maps with engineType="P2D" for the image quality to be same as before. The team is working on fixing the issue meanwhile.

Comment: I am not sure this helps if we have a vector normal map with a raster satellite map. That would force us to use no vector maps correct?

Comment: If you want to switch base layers between vector.normal.map and raster.satellite.map you can't use P2D engineType indeed. But if you want to use only raster map types, then you should use P2D engineType for now to have the same image quality as before.